# Audience shows 0 contacts after a successful contacts import in Mailchimp

Tags: mailchimp

We have a free Mailchimp account and are stumped. We just ran a test contacts import from a CSV file with two email addresses. We've received the confirmation email that the import has completed with 2 contacts imported. The import also shows in the import history. Alas, when I go to the audience page I see 0 contacts. It's been 30 mins since the imports, so I recon I can eliminate the simple latency explanation. Thanks in advance for any pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the two emails I attempted to import had existed and been deleted from this audience. The logic of not importing into an audience a contact that had been deleted holds water in my view. However, keeping this question around because the logic of reporting "2 contacts have been imported," and then showing an empty contact list seems counterintuitive and is bound to stump others.